# What UI elements would improve my booking page?

Tags: usability, forms, user-behavior, mobile-application

I'm in the process of redeveloping a "request seat" page for a taxi sharing application that I am working on. Users can request a seat on a booking made by another user - this page allows them to view the cost implications of having an additional pickup/dropoff on a journey.

The below image is the current iteration:

[image]

A couple of issues I have with this screen:

- The manner in which the journey is structured implies that the taxi is going from **Great Holm - Shenley Brook End - Central Milton Keynes - whatever the user points in at pickup point B**. When really it should be **Great Holm - Shenley Brook End OR Pickup point B - Central Milton Keynes**. How can make the UX necessary adjustments to have it appear this way? In this example, Great Holm is the pickup point and Central Milton Keynes is the destination.
- Could the fare contribution layout section be improved in anyway? The user can contribute to the Estimated Fare (perhaps this should be reworded to Estimated Total Fare), before requesting a seat. The user is given a set "frozen" price which they can either increase from or decrease to, depending on where they can be picked up from. The +/- buttons currently look out of place, any ideas on how to improve them?
- If I wanted to add a map to this screen - where would it go? Should I make it appear from a dropdown button somewhere on the screen, or have it visible to the user from the get go. The issue here is mainly with bandwidth (so I'm leaning towards having it appear from a dropdown). It would allow for the screen to initially load with the minimum data requirement for the best speed.

Comment: Sorry for the down-vote, but I feel that this is very close to a review of your interface, with very little use in other situations and for other users. UX.SE usually close "review of my X" question. I'd like you to edit your question to be more general and more useful for future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: I think that since this is a request for solutions to specific problems rather than for a general opinion of the UI, it doesn't fall under the critique category.

Comment: Upvoted; IMO, it's a standard UI question.

Comment: There are too many questions being asked here. Can you refine it to one specific one? As a Q&A site each post needs to be distinct and individual otherwise you'll get different answers answering different parts of the question instead of answering the whole thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try giving each point of the journey its own item on the list, instead of combining the start and end of the route. Then the first point will be easier to understand. And the map - you can have a dedicated button for it on each row of the route points, to bring up the map centered on that point.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Mhgt.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I like this a lot - but two things 1) how would a user add an extra pick up point? 2) its hard to tell that the text box below the estimated fare dialog is the contribute fare option, how could this be improved?

Comment: +1
... but i would keep the "request seat" button much bigger

Comment: @methuselah I updated the UI a bit regarding these two points.